# How can I enable/disable update function from other script in Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

I have a slider in my unity application. So I want to have opportunity to change its value manually. To do that I need to disable slider's script Update() function when pause is clicked and enable it when resume is clicked.

Thank you!

Comment: enable/disable the component

Comment: Have a script to be in charge of the pausing instead and disable the component that contains your update function. Re-enable the component once the game resumes.

Answer (score 2):

Use a bool.
Like

```
bool isUpdateEnable;

void Update()
{
  if(isUpdateEnable)
  {
   // Do whatever you want
  }
}
```

Comment: It was a nice idea. Thank you, it works!

Comment: its also unnecessary.. as per my comment, if you disable te component, update and fixedupdate do not run..

Comment: Yeah just disable the component which is way more efficient. Now you are getting `Update` still called via Unity message which causes some unnecessary overhead

Answer (score 1):

Simply disable the according component:

[`Behaviour.enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html)

> Enabled Behaviours are Updated, disabled Behaviours are not.
>
> This is shown as the small checkbox in the inspector of the behaviour.

This is more efficient than a `bool` flag in the `Update` method since continuously calling the "empty" `Update` method causes unnecessary overhead.

Another side effect advantage is that you can also use `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` to implement additional behaviour for everytime the component is enabled or disabled.